# C# Image.Save ends in "Invalid Bmp"

Tags: c#, bitmap, in-memory, decoder

I try to create a memory stream of an object which is indeed a System.Drawing.Bitmap. The `MemoryStream` is later on saved on the disk as a temporary file.

This is the code:

```
object resource = TestData.ResourceManager.GetObject(key);      
...
if (resource is System.Drawing.Bitmap)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    Encoder myEncoder =  System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth;
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters();
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 16);

    ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)resource).Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    return memoryStream;
}
...
```

The memory stream is then saved:

```
string targetFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (MemoryStream resourceStream = ResolveAsStream(key))
{

    if (resourceStream == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find resource for key '" + key + "'.");
    }

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(targetFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
    {
         resourceStream.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
return targetFilePath;
```

The file is successfully created but when I try to open it, it tells me, that the image file is invalid (i.e. it cannot be opened by Paint or any other image viewer). Instead of using `ImageFormat.Bmp` I tried with `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`:

```
object resource = TestData.ResourceManager.GetObject(key);      
...
if (resource is System.Drawing.Bitmap)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    Encoder myEncoder =  System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth;
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters();
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 16);

    ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)resource).Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.MemoryBmp);
    return memoryStream;
}
...
```

But this actually fails with

> "value Cannot be null Parameter name: encoder"

It seems there is no codec specified for `MemoryBmp`. So how can I save the image correctly so that the `Bmp` file is valid?

Comment: I've seen similar problems using MemoryStream specifically.  Try replacing memorystream with FileStream (delete the temp file it creates).  See if that resolves it.  Also, just before `resourceStream.CopyTo(fs);` set `resourceStream.Position = 0;`

Comment: Replacing memoryStream with FileStream means serialize the object? e.g. new BinaryFormatter() bf; bf.Serialize(fs, System.Drawing.Bitmap)resource);

Comment: I still stuck with the issue